# Bluetooth Atheros 0cf3:3004 does not work in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: bluetooth, atheros

In the Bluetooth GUI, I can select "On", but Bluetooth remains disabled. I cannot select Visibility "On."  My computer is not connecting over Bluetooth to other devices. How do I turn on Bluetooth?
[image]

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f2:b420 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 058: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also

```
$ rfkill list all
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ uname -r
3.16.0-31-generic
$ dmesg | grep Blue
<no output>
```

Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Does bluetooth connect to other devices, or does not work at all? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command there.

Comment: No, it's not working at all. I added that output in the question.

Comment: Please specify your Ubuntu version and add also output of `uname -r` and `dmesg | grep Blue` commands.

Comment: Please read the answer. It should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with this device, but it has been fixed. You just need to upgrade your kernel using routine procedure. Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then turn off your computer and turn it on again. This is needed to reset bluetooth chip.

After that bluetooth should work.

There is also an issue sometimes that bluetooth can not be turned on using System Settings applet. In this case turn it on by the indicater at the top of the screen.